# How to tell KmlLayer about custom map projection?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, map-projections

I have a map with a custom projection (for maps.yandex.ru tiles) and default projection (Google and OSM tiles). When I add KmlLayer to map in the default projection it seems ok:
[image: Default projection]

But switching map to maps.yandex layer (in custom projection)...
[image: Custom projection]

and kml-objects are misplaced.

How do I tell KmlLayer about custom projection?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, any given object that has lat/lon (a,b) under a Mercator projection will have a different value than (a,b) under a custom projection. For example, if your custom projection was polar, the object would have distance from a fixed point and an angle from a fixed direction, and no lat/lon at all. So, the way to tell your KMLLayer about the custom projection would be to convert the coordinates of each object and rewrite the KML.

Comment: how i can access to kmllayer objects through gmaps js api v3 ?

Comment: or at least to xhr(?) result data to rewrite this before render ?